# How to connect google app engine with secret manager to Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to connect from a nodejs/typescript codebase running in GAE to a GCP managed Postgres db via secret manager.

I'm getting:

```
 Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project DATABASE_USER.
```

when I run it in GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you've granted Secrets Access to the GAE service account in IAM.

Then use the following code example to get your ENV vars from secret manager.

```
import * as path from 'path';
import {SecretManagerServiceClient} from '@google-cloud/secret-manager';
import deasync from 'deasync';


require('dotenv').config();

const SnakeNamingStrategy =
  require('typeorm-naming-strategies').SnakeNamingStrategy;

const googleProjectId = process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT;
const isInGAE = googleProjectId !== undefined;
const isLocalUsingCloudProxy = process.env.USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY !== undefined;


const getSecretSync = deasync((name: string, cb:any) => {
  const c = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
  
  c.accessSecretVersion({name: c.secretVersionPath(googleProjectId, name, "latest")}).then(([secret]) => {
    cb(null, secret.payload.data.toString());
  }).catch((err) => {
    cb(err);
  });
});

  

let config = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || 'localhost',
  port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT, 10) || 5432,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  synchronize: false,
  logging: false,
  subscribers: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'subscribers', '*.{ts,js}')],
  entities: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'models', '*.{ts,js}')],
  migrations: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'migrations', '*.{ts,js}')],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'models', '*.{ts,js}')],
    migrationsDir: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'migrations', '*.{ts,js}')],
  },
  namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
};


if (isInGAE || isLocalUsingCloudProxy) {
  config.username = getSecretSync("DATABASE_USER");
  config.password = getSecretSync("DATABASE_PASSWORD");
  config.database = getSecretSync("DATABASE_NAME");
  config.host = isInGAE ? "/cloudsql/" + getSecretSync("DATABASE_HOST") : 'localhost';
  config.port = isInGAE ? parseInt(getSecretSync("DATABASE_PORT"), 10) : 5432;
  console.log("dbuser", config.username);

}
```

It's important to note that the DATABASE_HOST should be in the form of the "Connection Name" on the SQL tab, like `project-id:us-central1:db-name`